# dead thermostat with RH RC jumper

Tags: thermostat

have dead White Rodgers select comfort II 1F90-51, 4 wire gas heat, elect AC, RC RH jumper (red wire to RH).  Using only heat mode now (though was just 75 yesterday but 33 last night!)

Needs replacement - Sunday only have a Honeywell CT2700 available 4 wire no RH or RC.

Can I use the CT2700 w/o issues, or is there something on heat or air end needing RC RH?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since there is only one R wire going into your thermostat, you should be able to use the CT2700 without an issue.  Take the red wire and connect it to the R terminal, and connect the rest of the wires to the same-named terminals on the CT2700 that they were connected to on the 1F90-51.

Comment: Exactly. The RC/RH split is there in case your AC and heat systems use separately derived transformers which are for some reason incompatible.  If the jumper is present, that does not apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The RC and RH terminals are Red Heat and Red Cool, a long time ago General Electric made HVAC systems with 2 transformers, 1 for Cool and 1 for Heat, thus the RH and RC terminals, thermostats come with a jumper wire between RC and RH so modern single transformer systems can run their Red thermostat wire to either RC or RH since they are jumpered